# I am trying to scrape some data and export it to a CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to scrape some data and export it to a CSV.

I don't need help with the CSV part, but what I am having trouble with is getting a variable out of a $.get() method.

Would I use .done()? .success()? I'm not quite sure how to go about it. I tried .done() (as far as I could figure out) and it didn't work.

```
$.get(link, function(response) {
    var nohover = $(response).find('#row-nohover').find("a");
    var total = "country;avg_temp;high_temp;low_temp;precipitation\n";
    for (var i = 0, len = nohover.length; i < len; i++) {
        var newLink = nohover[i].getAttribute("href");

        newLink = "http://www.domain.com" + newLink;

        $.get(newLink, function(response2) {
            var countryName = $(response2).find("#left-content").find("#headerfont").text();

            countryName = countryName.toLowerCase();
            countryName = capitalizeFirstLetter(countryName);

            //console.log($(response2).find("tbody:eq(2)").children());
            var avgTemp = $(response2).find("tbody:eq(2)").children()[1];
            var highTemp = $(response2).find("tbody:eq(2)").children()[2];
            var lowTemp = $(response2).find("tbody:eq(2)").children()[3];
            var precip = $(response2).find("tbody:eq(2)").children()[4];
            avgTemp = $(avgTemp).children()[1].innerHTML;
            highTemp = $(highTemp).children()[1].innerHTML;
            lowTemp = $(lowTemp).children()[1].innerHTML;
            precip = $(precip).children()[1].innerHTML;
            total += countryName + ";" + avgTemp + ";" + highTemp + ";" + lowTemp + ";" + precip + "\n";
            console.log(total);
        });
    }
});
```

Basically I want to get the `total` variable after the loop is finished. How do I do that?

Comment: Your data structure is all sorts of bad. You should use an array of objects: `[{countryName:"US", avgTemp:70, highTemp:101, lowTemp:0, precip:75}, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` will be incremented till `len - 1` without waiting for your inner AJAX requests to complete. Therefore, you need a variable other than `i` that you increment inside the callback of your inner AJAX request.

i.e.

```
for (var i = 0, processed = 0, len = nohover.length; i < len; i++) {

    ....

    $.get(newLink, function(response2) {

        ....

        console.log(total);

        processed++;
        if(processed === len -1) {
            // all done, you can use "total" now
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making multiple requests inside a loop.  You should think about storing these requests into some kind of structure that can let you know when *all* requests have completed successfully.

Have a look into jQuery deferreds [`.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function.

Comment: Yours is probably more correct than the other one, but I haven't really gotten a total grasp of promises and deferred objects, so for now I'll have to go with the other answer.